# Cannot force my floating divs always to center within container with CSS (yes, I removed float: left)

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am having a bad time trying to make things to work correctly with CSS! I have this display panel to show up 1-4 cells with text/image in each row. It's working fine if I have AT LEAST four cells. But if I need to display less than 4 (display=none) the cells gets aligned to the left and I would like that they get centered.

As I know that an image says more than a thousand words here it is:

[image]

And this is my HTML and CSS so far:

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="OEPanel.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./OEPanel.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="oepanelcontainer" class="OEContainer clearfix">
        <div id="oepanel" class="OEItems clearfix">
            <div id="oecell1" class="OECell"></div>
            <div id="oecell2" class="OECell"></div>
            <div id="oecell3" class="OECell" style="display:none;" ></div>
            <div id="oecell4" class="OECell" style="display:none;" ></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
.OEContainer {
    background-color: beige;
    min-height: 10em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 10px;
    max-width:1130px;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
    justify-content:space-between;
}

.OEItems {
    min-height: 10em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0px;
    max-width:1130px;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
    justify-content:space-between;
}

.clearfix::after { /* clearfix class to expand the element back to its normal height */
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
  
.OECell {
    background-color: lightblue;
    min-height: 10em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0px;
    width:250px;
    text-align:center;
    /* float: left; */
    margin: 5px;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
    .OEContainer {
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
    }
}
```

I appreciate any help! Thanks!

**IMPOrTANT NOTE**: I realized that until a certain width (until around 850px) the blocks WILL center, but when the width goes wider than this the blocks suddenly jump to the far left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply  `display: flex;` and `justify-content: center;` to the *direct*  parent of these items (i.e. to `#oepanel` ). No floating needed.

Addition after comment: You can add a media query where you add flex-wrap: wrap; to that rule below a certain width. (done below in your own media query)

```css
.OEContainer {
  background-color: beige;
  min-height: 10em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 1130px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#oepanel {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.OEItems {
  min-height: 10em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0px;
  max-width: 1130px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.clearfix::after {
  /* clearfix class to expand the element back to its normal height */
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.OECell {
  background-color: lightblue;
  min-height: 10em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 250px;
  text-align: center;
  /* float: left; */
  margin: 5px;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .OEContainer {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
  #oepanel {
    flex-wrap:wrap;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="OEPanel.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./OEPanel.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="oepanelcontainer" class="OEContainer clearfix">
    <div id="oepanel" class="OEItems clearfix">
      <div id="oecell1" class="OECell"></div>
      <div id="oecell2" class="OECell"></div>
      <div id="oecell3" class="OECell" style="display:none;"></div>
      <div id="oecell4" class="OECell" style="display:none;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: **Johannes** it "kind" of worked. OK, it will center the blocks but now when I squeeze the screen width it will squeeze the blocks together. Before they didn't center but when I reduced the width of the screen they will keep their width while they still fit side by side into the container. When they cannot stay side by side anymore they will rearrange themselves in a pile (one over the other). This is the behavior I expect. Any idea of how to do both things (auto-arrange, no width change and centering)?

Comment: You can add a media query where you add `flex-wrap: wrap;` to that rule below a certain width.

Comment: Super-cool! I already was thinking that it couldn't be achieved. This is exactly what I was after. I know a bit of CSS but it may be really tricky! Thank you very much for helping! :-)